# filtering Nested Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the next question/problem:

---

i am trying to join there tables and filter by one of them.

**content** model:

```
public function credits(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\models\Credit');
}
```

**credits** model:

```
public function person(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Person')->withDefault();
}
```

**person** model:

the person model has an attribute called **popularity** (important for the example)

```
public function image(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\models\Images_persons')->where('is_backdrop',0)->orderBy('vote_count','desc');
}
```

---

**Example:**

when I make a query of one film, I obtain many credits,so we are going to suppose that the **kill_bill** film, has 40 credits

**Kill_bill** has **40 credits** and each credit has only **one person**

what I am trying to do is only takes 5 credits of one film, filtered by the population of the persons.

**conclusion**: I search one film, i get the credits of the film make a join with the persons of that credits, i order by the person's popularity and then I take the first 5 credits, showing also the information of the persons.

---

try code:

```
$content_movie=$this->content::with([

      'credits'=>function($query){
            $query->limit('person',function($query2){
                 $query2->orderBy('popularity','desc')->take(5);
            })->with('person');
       },

 ])->where('slug',$args['slug'])->get(['id','name','collections_id','overview','release_date','status','video','vote_average']);
```

apart from this code I have tested many codes more, but I haven't been able to obtain any result